# Is Subversion polluting my project, or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 for a C# project; we're also using (company mandated) Subversion and Tortoise. After getting the latest files uploaded by my colleague, the project won't compile for me because I get the err msg:

"Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< .mine". Illegal characters in path."

A search revealed that this is in a file named "GOHRFTracker.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt"

I guess this (FileListAbsolute) is a Subversion-generated file. So why is it needed in order to compile? Can I simply delete the file, rename it, remove the offending "<<<<<<< .mine" or...???

Comment: I'd suggest that some subversion training is needed for your team

Comment: Uh.  CSProj files are VS.Net-controlled; you added a file, your colleague added a file, they committed first.  You get to merge the two together.

Comment: You could try the Agent SVN plugin for Visual Studio. It will let you use the actual version control menus that come as standard in the Visual Studio IDE (i.e. check out, check in, compare etc). It also has an option to do *file locking on check out*, which should reduce the chance of creating merge conflicts.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**<<<<<<<<<.mine** is a merge conflict marker, it arises when there are unresolved conflicts. It happens when two users commits the same file having conflicting changes.

**Solution is**:

Open the conflicted file and remove "**<<<<<<<<<.mine**" line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a really inaccurate description of why conflicts happen, and also a bad solution.

Answer (score 9):

That is a merge conflict marker. You and your colleague have conflicting changes in that project file.

Comment: It's not a file I explicitly altered (I didn't even know it existed until I seached for that offending text); so can I delete it? rename it? strip out the plethora of chevrons, or what?

Comment: See Mike's answer for a link to the reason the filelistabsolute.txt files exist. I would recommend DELETING the .csproj.filelistabsolute.txt from the repository and EXCLUDING it, for the same reason that I would recommend EXCLUDING the .SUO file - it is per user, per machine data that should not be version-tracked.

Answer (score 4):

Try the Agent SVN Subversion plugin for Visual Studio. I find it helps me to minimise these sort of merge/conflict issues.

Answer (score 2):

That means that SVN had a merge conflict on that file.  Did you get an conflict message the last time you updated your machine from the repository?

Also, a quick googling indicates that FileListAbsolute is generated by Visual Studio, not Subversion: [What are all these *.FileListAbsolute.txt files for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559045/what-are-all-these-filelistabsolute-txt-files-for)

Comment: I suspect that someone else got the merge conflict, didn't handle it properly and committed the conflicted file which left you with the mess to sort out.

Comment: @Steve Kaye +1 That's almost certainly what happened, this is a cardinal sin of version control - whoever did it should be identified and given SVN training as a matter of priority.

Comment: Ha, half the time SVN (Tortoise + Ankh) doesn't warn about these conflicts and I only find out when re-opening the solution.

And it's always fun when the <<<<< crap ends up in comment line.

Merging in SVN is always a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Using Tortoise, you need to resolve merge conflicts.  It's used to indicate the conflict and each parties contribution on where the conflict occurs.

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit conflicts which are present in that file.  SVN will then remove these itself once conflicts are resloved

Answer (score 1):

If you use Tortoise SVN:

Right Click on the debug folders in the bin and obj folders that Visual Studio creates > select Tortoise SVN > Unversion and Add to ignore list > Debug (recursively).

Clean out the contents of these folders and rebuild. 
Good Luck!